# How can I access IDeviceIdleController instance in Android M

Tags: android, reflection, android-6.0-marshmallow, powermanager

I'm exploring the changes in Android M preview release 1. Specifically, I want to know if I can programmatically check to see if my app is whitelisted from Doze and App Standby mode. I basically want the result of "adb shell dumpsys deviceidle". I attempted to get the instance of android.os.IDeviceIdleController via getSystemServices but it return null. when I do "adb shell service list" I get "56    deviceidle: [android.os.IDeviceIdleController]". If I can access the instance, then I an use java reflection to access the public method isPowerSaveWhitelistApp(string name).

Comment: Source code of M preview will be helpful, but until now can't find (probably not public). Google source from branch android-m-preview doesn't corresponds M preview binary image published officially.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `android.permission.DEVICE_POWER` (signature protected) to call the method. See the source code:

- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/af8ff4f/services/core/java/com/android/server/DeviceIdleController.java#1160
- https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/be59441/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge/RequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations.java#106